# Redis Insight shows keys with their doublequotes when using a Spring App

Tags: java, spring, serialization, redis, redisinsights

Yo,

I was using a redis client in node js with Redis insight and everything was smooth. Now I'm trying a Spring App with Jedis however every key I insert is surrounded by doublequotes which makes the Tree view feature of Redis insight to not work.

Here is my template config:

```java
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(@Nonnull RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        template.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        return template;
    }
```

I thought maybe something was wrong with the serializer, so I even tried something like this

```java
template.setStringSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(String.class));
```

However this doesn't seem a serializer issue since I checked the bytes and everything looks fine.

Searched Redis Insight settings for a little bit and couldn't find anything, any ideas?

[Using Spring and Jedis](https://prnt.sc/9Hiw6ZoUxHeK)

[Same app using node redis](https://prnt.sc/0sY7rZ-OZkm9)

Answer (score 1):

what delimiter do you use in key names?
I tried a key name with double quotes and used a colon as a delimiter, and it worked fine.
[image]